# Get value of custom attribute without providing class name and/or method name

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, nunit, custom-attributes

I know i'm repeating the question, I've went through some of the similar solutions but i'm looking for a different one.

I want to read value of a custom defined attribute. I have below piece of code that does it for me, but i don't want to hard code the class name and/or method name, because then it is not useful for me. I want to make this method reusable so that it can be used to read values from all the test methods available.

### Attribute definition:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class TestDataFile : Attribute
{
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

### Accessing attribute:

```
var attribute = (TestDataFile)typeof(DummyTest).GetMethod("Name").GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TestDataFile), false).First();
```

### Usage:

```
[TestFixture]
public class DummyTest
{
    [Test]        
    [TestDataFile(Name="filename.json")]
    [TestCaseSource("LoadTestData")]
    public void AlwaysTrue(Dictionary<string, string> testCaseData)
    {
        // use test data here
    }
}
```

Can we achieve this in c-sharp ? if yes, Please assist me with a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **TestCaseSource** instead of creating a new custom attribute and retrieving the values from it. Please find the sample code snippet to use TestCaseSource with parameters

```
[TestCaseSource("PrepareTestCases", new object[] { "filename.json" })]
```

---

Please add the static method with source name

```
protected static object[] PrepareTestCases(string param)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(param);
        return new object[] { }; // do return the object you need
    }
```

This will get the values of parameters..

Comment: Thank you @Sathish, it actually works the same way as in **@DataProvider** in TestNG. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use **StackFrame** to get a MethodBase reference to the calling method. Consider the following sample:

```
class Foo
{
    [TestDataFile(Name = "lol")]
    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        var attribute = Helper.GetAttribute();
        Console.WriteLine(attribute.Name);
    }

    [TestDataFile(Name = "XD")]
    public void SomeOtherMethod()
    {
        var attribute = Helper.GetAttribute();
        Console.WriteLine(attribute.Name);
    }
}
```

And our helper method where the magic actually takes place:

```
public static TestDataFile GetAttribute()
{
    var callingMethod = new StackFrame(1).GetMethod();
    var attribute = (TestDataFile)callingMethod.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TestDataFile), false).FirstOrDefault();
    return attribute;
}
```

Testing:

```
private static void Main()
{
    var foo = new Foo();
    foo.SomeMethod();
    foo.SomeOtherMethod();
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

You can get more info about StackFrame in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stackframe(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, This is possible only if we call _**GetAttribute()**_ inside the test methods, but in my case i want to get the attribute's value in _**TestCaseSource()**_  method.